# what does a colon (:) do in a linear mixed effects model analysis?

Tags: r, operators

Let me clarify that I am a complete beginner at R.

I'm working on a problem and having a bit of trouble understanding a formula I'm supposed to use in a linear mixed effects model analysis of a dataset, more specifically this formula,

```r
ModelName <- lmer(outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor1:predictor2 + (random_structure), data = DatasetName)
```

I don't know what the predictor1:predictor2 part of it means, could anyone please help me understand or link to something I can read to understand?

I've run the code and it gives an additional output for the predictor2 part of the formula which doesnt happen when you dont include that part.

Comment: In this case it is defining the interaction term between predictor 1 & 2.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! You may be new to R, but you ask a *great* question!

As you probably know already, the `+` operator separates terms in a model.

`Y ~ a + b + c` means that the response is modeled by a linear combination of a, b, and c.

The colon operator denotes interaction between the items it separates, for example:

`Y ~ a + b + a:b` means that the response is modeled by a linear combination of a, b, *and* the interaction between a and b.

I hope this helps!

Rose Hartman explains how interactions affect linear models, and why it’s important to consider them in *Understanding Interactions in Linear Models* https://education.arcus.chop.edu/understanding-interactions/

Comment: Thank you for the help! That does clear things up a bit, but I'm still a bit confused on what it does practically, as in if i did run the code, what would be the difference caused due to the interaction?